# Cant run react-native app in iOS but, i upgrade my xcode to 12

Tags: react-native-ios

When I run my app in the terminal I get this error:

> error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it
> exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider
> building your app with Xcode.app, by opening app.xcworkspace.

But when I try to run the `app.xcworkspace` I get another error:

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
> '-L-L/Users/josecuetosimancas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-arkyvclpjmalkpagzxpefttuuars/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BoringSSL-GRPC'
> ld: library not found for -lBoringSSL-GRPC clang: error: linker
> command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

this is my PODFILE:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'app' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  target 'appTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'app-tvOS' do
  # Pods for app-tvOS

  target 'app-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end

and my package.json

{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios --simulator=\"iPhone 11 Pro Max\"",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "android:apk": "cd ./android && ./gradlew assembleRelease",
    "android:aab": "cd ./android && ./gradlew bundleRelease",
    "android:clean": "cd ./android && ./gradlew clean"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "2.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^3.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.6",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.0.8",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.9.9",
    "@react-native-community/picker": "^1.8.1",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "^4.2.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^9.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^9.3.5",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^7.10.3",
    "accounting": "^0.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.3",
    "react-native-dots-pagination": "^0.1.11",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^7.3.0",
    "react-native-navigation-hooks": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-progress-steps": "^1.3.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-stars": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-user-avatar": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "@types/accounting": "^0.4.1",
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.165",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.63.2",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.9.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.27.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.27.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.1",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```